# Data deduplication Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a journey.
My data extension has two primaryKey, SubcriberKey and ProductID

So i would like that my contact entry  in journey everytime that they will buy.
I set in JourneySetting re-entry everytime.

How does Journey Builder manage duplicates in entry Data Extension? Will only the first row in the data extension enter and the rest will get blocked withoht contact entry?

In the to Process Entry Source Data valuation I have To evaluate all records in a data extension o newRecord?

in this scenario Journey won't do the deduplication since the customer can enter multiple times?

Comment: By duplicates do you mean multiple entries of the SubscriberKey, or multiples of the Email/Phone (where more than one SubKey has the same Email/Phone)?

Comment: multiples of the Email/Phone (where more than one SubKey has the same Email/Phone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set contact re-entry setting in journey or else it errors and doesn't pass validation.

If you already have a contact going through the journey and same contact tries to enter. The duplicate will not be entered into the journey. Depending on your primary key setting it could still get added to the DE though.

Comment: If I have different subscriberkey with thesame email?

Comment: contact key/subscriber key determines if a contact is unique. So different subscriber keys with same emails will be treated as different subscribers.